# Have access to UITableViewCell from heightForRow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PostTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    return cell.imageView.frame.size.height + 40;

}
```

What I want to do is be able to access the cell's properties somehow. I want the cell's height to be equal to the height of the image in the cell's image view. I don't think this is working.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to access the cell. Your table's data source or some other object besides your cell should be managing that image. Ask that object for the image and take its size.

Treating your cell as a data container is tangling up your model, view, and controller layers and is likely to make changes more difficult down the line.

Comment: Ok, so my image is returned from a JSON file and is stored in an NSDictionary. Should I just access the file, get the image, and then return it's size?

Comment: No, get it out of the dictionary.

Comment: SOrry, that's what I meant. Thanks.